# Docker .net core angular identityserver 4 app failing to login

Tags: angular, docker, asp.net-core, identityserver4

I have a .net core (using identityserver4 for authentication) angular app that I am deploying to docker. The app works fine while debugging in vs but when I deploy to docker and specify for the app to use the certificate (Which Identityserver4 needs when in production mode), I get the following error.

    `fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.DefaultAntiforgery[7]
      An exception was thrown while deserializing the token.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.AntiforgeryValidationException: The antiforgery token could not be decrypted.
 ---> System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: The key {6e35592f-c840-4efd-8d8c-1d5b95804121} was not found in the key ring.`

I have tried different things for about 11 hours so far. I have absolutely cleared all cache and other data but that made no difference.

UPDATE:
I have now built this application on a different machine and now when I run in docker, the error still comes up but I am able to successfully login!

Is there any explanation for this? I have checked that I have the same SDK's installed on both machines.

Comment: hi, probably you started two docker instances, but did not share the keys?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed!

In the end, it turned out that the issue was limited to my specific, unique production environment and also a 'bug' in .net core 3.0. I don't fully understand the problem but it relates to TLS. See the [link](https://github.com/dotnet/SqlClient/issues/222) that fixed the issue.